# Where can I find good examples of testing a Thor script with RSpec?

Tags: rspec, thor

Where can I find good examples of testing a Thor script with RSpec?

My searches have so far not turned up anything good.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try out Thor's own repo at https://github.com/wycats/thor/tree/master/spec

Comment: amazing. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I'm trying to do rspec tests for thor in my [homedir](http://github.com/docwhat/homedir) project (in the homedir3 branch, at the moment).  Look in the [CLI_spec.rb](https://github.com/docwhat/homedir/blob/homedir3/spec/lib/homedir/cli_spec.rb) file.

I don't claim they are the paragon of unit tests but it's something to look at.