# Using default options when testin thor tasks

Tags: thor

I would like to test thor tasks with rspec, but when calling them from rspec I have two requirements:

1. I would like to have Thor Class instance available
2. I would like to call tasks with default options (as it will be called from command line)

I am not able to achieve both of these at the same time, consider following code:

```
require 'thor'
require 'thor/runner'
class App < Thor
  method_option :foo , :default => "foovalue"
  desc "xlist", "list"
  def xlist(search="")
    p options
  end
end

app = App.new

app.xlist
app.invoke(:xlist)

App.start ARGV
```

Output is:

```
> ruby contrib/thor_test.rb xlist
{}
{}
{"foo"=>"foovalue"}
```

In the first two examples, I can call task through instance but default options are not passed to method (which makes spec unrealistic)

In the third example, I get default options but I can't set expectations on class instance, neither I can stub any methods which makes it hard to test. That is happening because class instance is created on the fly.

Answer (score 3):

If you ask how you can test thor cli utility, I read through the thor specs as suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9085513/1638982). Examples [here](https://github.com/wycats/thor/blob/master/spec/thor_spec.rb) were particularly helpful and could be used directly.

Spec:

```
require 'my_thor'

describe MyThor do
  it "should work" do
    args = ["command", "--force"]
    options = MyThor.start(args)
    expect(options).to eq({ "force" => true })
  end
end
```

Code:

```
class MyThor < Thor
  desc "command", "do something"   
  method_option :force, :type => :boolean, :aliases => '-f'
  def command
    return options
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't address how to test the **default** options, since you're passing in '--force' explicitly

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do extract default options for a Thor command by:

1. Getting Thor's internal representation of the options list for that command
2. Building a `Thor::Options` object from that command list
3. Using that `Thor::Options` object to parse an empty array of options, which returns a hash of only the defaults.

The code is in `get_default_options_for_command` below.  Honestly, I'm hoping there's a better way to do it, but I couldn't find one.

Once you've got a Thor object, you can replace its options to include those defaults plus whatever other options you want to add, then run it with `#xlist`.

I wrote this all up using your example above:

```
require 'thor'

def get_default_options_for_command(klass,command_name)
  option_precursors = klass.all_commands[command_name].options
  parser = Thor::Options.new(option_precursors)
  parser.parse([])
end

class App < Thor

  desc "xlist", "list"
  method_option :foo , :default => "foovalue"
  method_option :bar
  def xlist(search="")
    puts "search: #{search}"
    puts "options: #{options}"
  end
end

app = App.new
xlist_default_opts = get_default_options_for_command(App,'xlist')
new_opts = { :bar => 3 }

app.options = xlist_default_opts.merge(new_opts)
app.xlist('search-term')
```

The output is:

```
$ ./test.rb
search: search-term
options: {"foo"=>"foovalue", "bar"=>3}
```