# Requiring a thor task in my rspec results in undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, thor

I'm trying to write a very basic rspec to for my Thor task, however when trying to require (or load) the task it fails, giving NoMethodError ('undefined method ...') for the various Thor class-level methods (desc, method_option, class_option etc)

```rb
require "spec_helper"
require Rails.root.join('lib/tasks/test_task.thor')

describe 'TestTask' do

  it "is instantiated ok" do
    TestTask.new
  end
end
```

As you can see I'm testing in the environment of a rails app.

The thor task itself executes fine from the command line.

I've looked through the Thor specs, as suggested elsewhere ([Where can I find good examples of testing a Thor script with RSpec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061988/where-can-i-find-good-examples-of-testing-a-thor-script-with-rspec/9085513#9085513))

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer that I've found is to use `load` rather than `require`
(I thought I had tested this, but perhaps I was mistaken)

so:

`require 'thor'
load File.join(Rails.root.join('lib/tasks/test_task.thor'))`

Answer (score 2):

Create `Thorfile` in the root directory. It'll be loaded each time thor command is run in the project.

```
# Thorfile
# load rails environment for all thor tasks (optionally)
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'development'
require File.expand_path('config/environment.rb')

Dir["#{__dir__}/lib/tasks/*.thor"].sort.each { |f| load f }
```

This will load all thor files before running thor tasks.

Now load Thorfile in `rails_helper.rb`:

```
# spec/rails_helper.rb
require 'thor'
load Rails.root.join('Thorfile')
```

Now you can test your task without loading task at the top like this:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe TestTask do
  subject { described_class.new }

  let(:run_task) { subject.invoke(:hello, [], my_option: 42) }

  it "runs" do
    expect { run_task }.not_to raise_error
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was solved by using `require <file>` instead of `require_relative`